# What is the correct conjunction or punctuation for the following sentence?

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions

I have two sentences as follows:

1. We don't know what we should do if the worst case happens.
2. The worse case is when the math teacher does not allow us to use calculators in the test.

I want to combine them into a single sentence. I am thinking of the following options but not sure which one is the correct one.

> We don't know what we should do if the worst case happens; the math
>   teacher does not allow us to use calculators in the test.

or

> We don't know what we should do if the worst case happens---the math
>   teacher does not allow us to use calculators in the test.

or

> We don't know what we should do if the worst case -- the math teacher does not allow us to use calculators in the test -- happens.

Comment: Hard to say, because I can't see the connection between the two parts of the sentence.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: the second part of the sentence is supposed to be the worst case scenario, at least that's how I get it

Comment: Then a simple ‘and’ between ‘happens’ and ‘the math teacher’ might do it.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: I think you should post it as an answer, I will be happy to upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

> We don't know what we should do if the worst case happens, which is
>   that the math teacher does not allow us to use calculators in the
>   test.

Comment: "We don't know what we should do if the worst case, which is that the math teacher does not allow us to use calculators in the test, happens." might be OK.

Comment: @CounterTerrorist: You seem to think that if the second clause doesn't come ***right*** after the phrase "worst case", it won't be understood that it's what it refers to. But it *will* be understood.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to fix it to my mind:

> We don't know what we should do if the worst case happens and the math
>   teacher does not allow us to use calculators in the test.

Comment: Somewhat ambiguous: it can mean that the worst case is that the math, etc., but can also mean that the worst case is unspecified and two things will occur.

Comment: @msh210: Nah, think of the context.

Comment: This. This right here is the answer, @CounterTerrorist.

Answer (score 3):

If, as proposed in a comment to the question, the math's teacher's disallowing the use of calculators is the "worst case" spoken of, and if I wanted to preserve the sentence in the question as closely as possible, then I'd use *that*:

> We don't know what we should do if the worst case happens, that the math teacher does not allow us to use calculators in the test.

or

> We don't know what we should do if the worst case happens: that the math teacher does not allow us to use calculators in the test.

Comment: I don't agree with the comma placement at all. Misplaced commas are my worst nightmare in English language.

Comment: Oh dear. I don't particularly mind the comma, but the semicolon looks awful to me. Whatever - @Barrie's *"and"* seems best to me. The possibility of ambiguity seems inconceivable to me, since it presupposes that there must be some *other* concurrent worst case scenario that the writer hasn't explicitly specified. Asteroid strike during the exam? WW3 starts? The mind boggles.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the colon is the best way to make it clear that the lack of calculators is the worst-case scenario, and that a slight recasting of the second half will also make it simpler:

> We don't know what we should do if the worst case happens: not being allowed to use calculators during the test.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also assuming, as suggested in the comments, that the "worst case" implies the need for calculators.

If that is case, I believe your original choice of the semicolon is appropriate, since it is intended to link two closely related independent clauses (which is what you've got).

> We don't know what we should do if the worst case happens.

and

> The math teacher does not allow us to use calculators in the test.

Answer (score -1):

I decided to use this one:

> We don't know what we should do if the worst case -- the math teacher
>   does not allow us to use calculators in the test -- happens.

Comment: For those who down vote this answer, please give me the reason. I will consider your advice and change my decision.

Comment: This is an excellent example of a "broken-backed sentence".  I.e. a sentence with a long clause between the subject (*the worst case*) and the verb (*happens*).  Broken-backed sentences are notoriously difficult to read and understand.